# Reword "increasingly too late"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, writing

How should I fix a sentence which says "As X disappears, it is increasingly too late to do Y with X"?  The sentence seems awkward to me, but "too late" is an adjective, so is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: So far, I have "As X disappears, there are fewer remaining X to Y", but I'm curious if there are other ways to recast the sentence since the "too-late-ness" is what I want to emphasize.

Comment: The problem is simply that if something's already *too late*, it can't become any more so - that's like saying *"As X dies, he is increasingly too dead to do Y"*.

Comment: *As X's health deteriorates, he is increasingly too unhealthy to do Y*?

Comment: Well, obviously there are marginal cases that vary according to exactly what *"too"* modifies, but by and large it's either *"too late"* to do something, or it's not. You'd probably be better avoiding *"too"* completely, and going for something like *"As X disappears, it is increasingly difficult to do Y with what remains"*. It might depend a bit on exactly what X and Y actually are.

Comment: -1 research effort missing. Question is request to rewrite -- see [faq]. Voting to close Off Topic.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: How do you know how much effort I put into the researching an answer?  You don't find it rude to claim otherwise? The question is very clearly one about word choice and usage.  Honestly, I would have liked someone to come up with an answer that emphasizes the disappearing possibility, but as no one could, I simply accepted what was there.

Comment: @Neil: How about *"X diminishes to the point where not enough remains to do Y [with it]"*?

Comment: @NeilG We only know what you disclose in the question. Note the comment is not "no research effort" but "research effort missing". The [faq] expands on this; also, see *[How to Ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)*: **“Tell us** what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer” [*emphasis added*].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence has a problem because "too late" is not a matter of degree.  "Too late" is a binary category -- either it is or it isn't -- so it makes no sense to talk about "increasingly too late".  So what is changing over time?  My guess is that your real meaning is:

> As X disappears, it is increasingly difficult to do Y with X.

or, even better:

> As X disappears, the chances of doing Y with X diminish to nothing.